# What to use instead of SimpleJdbcTestUtils?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, jdbc

I am trying to set up a database test using Spring and DBUnit. I have a script to run before each test. The code below works but `SimpleJdbcTemplate` **is deprecated**. The method `executeSqlScript` is being moved to JdbcTestUtil as part of the 3.2 release but we're on 3.1.x. What to use instead?

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class MyTestScript{

    @Autowired
    public DataSource dataSource;
    @Autowired
    public Resource script;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        SimpleJdbcTestUtils.executeSqlScript(
            new SimpleJdbcTemplate(dataSource), script, true);
    }

    @Test
    public void testInsert() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just suppress the warning and go on. Once you switch to Spring 3.2, the transition will be trivial (remove all the `Simple` prefixes). There is no real reason to avoid `SimpleJdbcTemplate` at all costs in these tests, as its whole functionality is in `JdbcTemplate` under the same name.